# Are my pots oven-safe?

Tags: oven, cookware, pot

My pots are

1. WearEver Cook & Strain Stainless Steel 1.5-Quart Saucepan

   Model No.:      A8342264
2. Tramontina 3-Quart Sauce Pan, Stainless Steel

   Model No.:      80154/516

The handle of the first one is steel, while the handle of the second one seems to be a mix of steel and black rubber (or something that looks similar to rubber, and you can google and check similar images)

Can I bake or roast chicken drumsticks in either pot inside an oven? How much should the baking temperature be?

I have been using both pots on cooktops to boil food. Sometimes I forgot to watch,  and the water was dried out, and the pots were burnt and became  black. 
If I put the pots inside an oven with only chicken inside the pots and without adding water (supposedly?), will that burn the pots as well? Why not?

Answer (score 3):

**WearEver Cook & Strain Stainless Steel 1.5-Quart Saucepan**

From [Amazon Q/A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00061U43Q):

> **Question**: Is this pan oven safe?
>   **Answer**: Oven safe to 500ºF if handles are all stainless steel. Oven safe to 350 ºF if handles have any silicone or phenolic parts. The oven should be completely preheated before placing the pan in the oven to avoid thermal shock. Cookware should not be used in the microwave or on outdoor grills. (*per the users manual*)

---

**Tramontina 3-Quart Sauce Pan, Stainless Steel**

From the [Walmart website:](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Tramontina-3-Qt-Tri-Ply-Clad-Sauce-Pan-with-Lid-Stainless-Steel/23000704)

> This saucepan is oven safe up to 500 degrees Fahrenheit

Note that the website shows an all-metal handle!

---

For recommended temperatures etc., see your various recipes for chicken or whatever you are planning to roast.